# How to get a bitmap from canvas

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, android-canvas

To scale to a small size bitmap, I have created following

val dst = RectF(5f, 0f,  scalledWidth, scalledHeight)
canvas.drawBitmap( bitmap40, null, dst, null)

But the problem is i need the resized bitmap from canvas.
How to do that ?

Comment: A `Canvas` is just a wrapper around a `Bitmap` that lets you draw on it - you have to provide that bitmap, either through the `Canvas` constructor or with `setBitmap`. So just keep a reference to that bitmap! Also since you're not doing anything special with the canvas, are you sure you don't want to use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` instead?

Comment: @cactustictacs I have tried Bitmap.createScaledBitmap but my iamge get pixelated

Comment: @cactustictacs

  Log.e("width: ",bitmapLast.width.toString())
        Log.e("height: ",bitmapLast.height.toString())
        canvas.drawBitmap( bitmapLast, null, dst, null)
        Log.e("After: ","".toString())
        Log.e("width: ",bitmapLast.width.toString())
        Log.e("height: ",bitmapLast.height.toString())

I tried this,
Both the place befare and after canvas , the bitmap size is same in the log print

Comment: @AnandS: Use formatting to display.  ```Log.e("width: ",bitmapLast.width.toString()) Log.e("height: ",bitmapLast.height.toString()) canvas.drawBitmap( bitmapLast, null, dst, null) Log.e("After: ","".toString()) Log.e("width: ",bitmapLast.width.toString()) Log.e("height: ",bitmapLast.height.toString())```I tried this, Both the place befare and after canvas , the bitmap size is same in the log print

Comment: Use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` with `filter` set to true if you want to use smooth scaling to avoid the pixellation. And I think you're getting confused with the `Canvas` - you create your smaller output bitmap, right? `bitmapSmall` or whatever. Then you create a canvas for it, `canvas = Canvas(bitmapSmall)`. Then when you do `canvas.drawBitmap(bigBitmap...)` you're drawing the *contents* of `bigBitmap` into `smallBitmap` through *its Canvas* (and maybe using `Rect`s to define source and destination regions on the bitmaps). The bitmap **dimensions** are fixed when you create them